# Assigning BigInt stores wrong number (number+1)

Tags: javascript, bigint

I want to define a `BigInt` number in JavaScript. But when I assign it, the wrong number is stored. In fact 1 is added to the number when storing.

```
let num = BigInt(0b0000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
console.log(num)                // Output: 1152921504606846976n
console.log(num.toString(2))    // Output: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So the number stored is `1152921504606846976`, but it should be `11529215046068469765`. Why is that?

Comment: Wrap your binary literal in a strng and pass that to `BigInt` instead

Comment: Not related to `BigInt` - it's `0b0000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` which is wrong before `BigInt` has a chance to interact with it.

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you, wrapping it in a string works with `BigInt("0b00...1")`. But why is that working and my approach not?

Comment: @VLAZ What is wrong with the binary number?

Comment: @Codey As VLAZ mentioned, the literal `0b00011...` is "evaluated" as `1152921504606847000` and then passed to BigInt, it's like using `BigInt(1152921504606847000)`, the number being passed to BigInt is incorrect when you're passing into the function

Comment: @Codey because the number you have is too large for JS to handle. Once you produce it, *you have already lost precision*.

Comment: @NickParsons @ VLAZ ah ok got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a Number to a BigInt can't create bits that weren't there before.
`0b1` (just like `1`) is a Number literal, so it creates a Number.
`0b1n` (just like `1n`) is a BigInt literal, so it creates a BigInt.

By writing `BigInt(0b1)`, you're first creating a Number and then converting that to a BigInt. As long as the value is 1, that works just fine; once the value exceeds what you can losslessly store in a `Number` [1], you'll see that the value of the final BigInt won't match the literal you wrote down. Whether you use binary (`0b...`), decimal, or hex (`0x...`) literals doesn't change any of that.
(And just to be extra clear: there's no reason to write `BigInt(123n)`, just like you wouldn't write `Number(123)`. `123n` already is a BigInt, so there's nothing to convert.)

A simple non-BigInt way to illustrate what's happening is to enter `12345678901234567890` into your favorite browser's DevTools console: you can specify Number literals of any length you want, but they'll be parsed into an IEEE754 64-bit "double", which has limited precision. Any extra digits in the literal simply can't be stored, though of course each digit's *presence* affects the magnitude of the number.

[1] Side note: this condition is more subtle than just saying that `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the threshold, though that constant is related to the situation: any integral number below `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` can be stored losslessly, but there are plenty of numbers above `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` that can also be represented exactly. Random example: `1e20`.