# Why is 1 being added to my large number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
BigInt(9223372036854775807) // 9223372036854775808n
```

I don't often work with large numbers so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but why is this not `9223372036854775807n`?

I expect `BigInt(9223372036854775807)` to be `9223372036854775807n`.

Comment: `BigInt("9223372036854775807")` or `9223372036854775807n` .. your literal is exceeding otherwise `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. What I'm saying is that `9223372036854775807` is a `Number` literal and is failing the point if used to init the `BigInt`

Comment: If you want a `BigInt` with a value of `9223372036854775807`, you should explicitly specify the n suffix to indicate that it's a BigInt: `const mpliang = 9223372036854775807n;
`

Comment: Related: [Assigning BigInt stores wrong number (number+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70968922)

Answer (score -3):

```js
console.log(9223372036854775807)//9223372036854776000


console.log(BigInt(9223372036854776000))

console.log(BigInt(9223372036854776000) === 9223372036854775808n)


console.log(BigInt(9223372036854775807) === 9223372036854775808n)


console.log(BigInt("9223372036854775807") )//expect
```

`9223372036854775807` is a `Number`, precision has already been lost before becoming `BigInt`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?